# Modify and wrap xml nodes with nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have an xml document with fragments like the following:

```
<x>
  abcd
  <z>ef</z>
  ghij
</x>
```

I want to find the text "defg" inside the  node, and modify that  node to the following:

```
<x>
  abc
  <y>
    d<z>ef</z>g
  </y>
  hij
</x>
```

This means creating a new node that has bit of x.text and other children inside.

I can find the node which includes the text, but I don't know how to break it up, and wrap just the matching section inside the `<y>` tags.

Any ideas that can point me in the right direction are most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I understand that inside the x element there are three children: a text (abcd), a z (ef), and another text element (ghij). I could treat each child, processing their contents and then re-creating a new children structure. Is there any other way around it? A simpler, more elegant shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

What about turning it into a sting and then use a regex to change it, and then parse it with nokogiri again.

```
sting = some_xml.to_s
# => '<x>abcd<z>ef</z>ghij</x>'

splits = sting.match(/(.)<z>(.*)<\/z>(.)/)

new_string = sting.gsub(splits[1], "<y>#{splits[1]}").gsub(splits[3], "#{splits[3]}</y>")

Nokogiri::XML(new_string)
```